# Google Analytics from Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to track events from the spring boot, I have used the google analytics for that
But events are not getting tracked in dashboard.

```
private GoogleAnalyticsService gaService;

@GetMapping
String testEvents() throws ServletException {
    gaService.trackEvent();
    return "Event tracked";
}
```

```
@Service
public class GoogleAnalyticsService {
    
    @Value("${GA_TRACKING_ID_2}")
    private String GA_TRACKING_ID_2;
   
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleAnalyticsService.class);
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public void trackEvent() throws ServletException {
        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
            builder
                .setScheme("https")
                .setHost("www.google-analytics.com")
                .setPath("/collect")
                .addParameter("v", "1") // API Version.
                .addParameter("tid", GA_TRACKING_ID_2) // Tracking ID / Property ID.
                // Anonymous Client Identifier. Ideally, this should be a UUID that
                // is associated with particular user, device, or browser instance.
                .addParameter("cid", "555")
                .addParameter("t", "event2") // Event hit type.
                .addParameter("ec", "example2") // Event category.
                .addParameter("ea", "test action2"); // Event action.
            URI uri = builder.build();
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set("user-agent", "test-User");
            final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class);
            logger.info("response: {}", response.getStatusCode());


            // Handle the response if needed
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // Handle the exception
            throw new ServletException("Problem building URI", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also follow this link made all the changes mentioned still events are not getting publish in dashboard. Spring boot log shows me that the request is successful, but nothing appear in Google Analytics dashboard.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/integrating-with-analytics?tab=java#top

[Google Analytics from Spring Boot 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151765/google-analytics-from-spring-boot-2)

Can anyone please tell what I am missing here.